# JQuery .eq selector not selecting elements

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make a simple image rotator that will rotate through a number of set images in a php array. The array out puts the image correctly, the styles work, even the JQuery that fades out the active element. It just can't find the next element and using console.log(), I know it is calculating the correct one. I even tried to put a number (like 3) in .eq() to see if it will select that element, and it won't. Here is my code:

PHP code:

```
$randomNumber = rand(0);

$performanceImages = array("09_15_11-Lorton_opening_088.jpg", 
                            "09_15_11-Lorton_opening_120.jpg",
                            "09_15_11-Lorton_opening_123.jpg",
                            "09_15_11-Lorton_opening_125.jpg",
                            "09_15_11-Lorton_opening_126.jpg",
                            "09_15_11-Lorton_opening_128-150x150.jpg",
                            "09_15_11-Lorton_opening_131.jpg",
                            "09_15_11-Lorton_opening_132.jpg",
                            "09_15_11-Lorton_opening_135-199x300.jpg",
                            "09_15_11-Lorton_opening_137-150x150.jpg",
                            "09_15_11-Lorton_opening_144.jpg",
                            "09_15_11-Lorton_opening_161.jpg");

$randomNumber = rand(0, (sizeof($performanceImages) - 1) );

for ($cnt = 0; $cnt < sizeof($performanceImages); $cnt++) {
    if ($cnt == $randomNumber) {
        echo '<div id="rotator-image" class="active" style="display:block;"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/rotation-images/'.$performanceImages[$cnt].'" /></div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div id="rotator-image" style="display:none;"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/rotation-images/'.$performanceImages[$cnt].'" /></div>';
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar-image-rotator {
width: 180px;
height: 263px;
position: relative; 
}

#rotator-image {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;    
}
```

JQuery:

```
function sidebarImageRotator(){

var count = $("#sidebar-image-rotator").children("#rotator-image").length;
//console.log(count);
var active = $('#rotator-image.active').index();
//console.log(active);

if ((active + 1) < count) {
    var next = active + 1;
} else {
    var next = 0;
}
//console.log(next);

//change div classes
$("#rotator-image.active").fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $("#rotator-image.active").removeClass("active").css("display","none");
    $('#sidebar-image-rotator').find('#rotator-image').eq(next).addClass('active').fadeIn('slow', function () {
        $('#rotator-image.active').css('display', 'block');
    })
}); 
}  

function startTimer() {
//timer for the box
window.timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    $("#sidebar-image-rotator").timer();
}, 7000);

jQuery.fn.timer = function() {
    sidebarImageRotator();
}
}
```

startTimer() is being called with the page is loaded.

Comment: If this is JS related question please post resulting HMTL instead of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML id's must be unqiue. jQuery is only ever going to find the first id, change to using classes instead.

Something like the following

Example PHP loop :

```
for ($cnt = 0; $cnt < sizeof($performanceImages); $cnt++) {
    if ($cnt == $randomNumber) {
        echo '<div class="rotator-image active" style="display:block;"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/rotation-images/'.$performanceImages[$cnt].'" /></div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="rotator-image" style="display:none;"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/rotation-images/'.$performanceImages[$cnt].'" /></div>';
    }
}
```

Example CSS

```
.rotator-image {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;    
}
```

Example jQuery

```
var count = $("#sidebar-image-rotator").children(".rotator-image").length;
//console.log(count);
var active = $('.rotator-image.active').index();
//console.log(active);

if ((active + 1) < count) {
    var next = active + 1;
} else {
    var next = 0;
}
//console.log(next);

//change div classes
$(".rotator-image.active").fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $(".rotator-image.active").removeClass("active").css("display","none");
    $('#sidebar-image-rotator').find('.rotator-image').eq(next).addClass('active').fadeIn('slow', function () {
        $('.rotator-image.active').css('display', 'block');
    })
}); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks much! I used this same script on another site and I used id's without any problem. I'll just use classes from now on I guess.

Answer (score 2):

the `id` attribute should be unique; your selector `#rotator-image` will return the first element with *id=rotator-image* and ignore the rest.  You could select on the id explicitly instead:

```
$('#sidebar-image-rotator').find('[id=rotator-image]').eq(next)
```

A better idea would be to use some other attribute on your elements like `rel` or `data-type` or whatever.

```
<div rel='rotator-image' ... ></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Think this is the problem

```
if ((active + 1) < count) {
        **var next = active + 1;**
    } else {
        var next = 0;
    }
```

You need to declare the **var next** outside of the function.. Otherwise every time the function is called it be replaced by a new instance